# How to vary start parameters in systemd service based on file existence?

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to write a service file for OpenLDAP. What I've got so far is:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenLDAP server daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/slapd/slapd.pid
ExecStartPre=-/bin/mkdir /var/run/slapd
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown openldap:openldap /var/run/slapd
ExecStart=/srv/openldap-latest/lib/slapd -h "ldap:/// ldaps:/// ldapi:///" -u openldap -g openldap -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The problem is the "-F /etc/ldap/slapd.d" bit. When OpenLDAP is first set up, this directory doesn't exist, so you have to specify "-f /etc/ldap/slapd.conf" instead. I cannot see how to do this with systemd, though.

One option might be to define TWO different units - one starts if slapd.d exists and one starts if slapd.d doesn't exist - but the service still needs to be called the same thing otherwise administrators are going to get very confused, so I don't think that idea works out.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

What about adding:

```
 ExecStartPre=-/bin/mkdir /etc/ldap/slapd.d
```

?

Comment: `mkdir -p` perhaps, so it doesn't fail if the directory does exist... Or maybe the `-` accomplishes the same thing, I guess...

Comment: @twalberg `man systemd.service` confirms that the leading dash tells `systemd` to ignore the possible failure of the command.

Comment: Whilst I appreciate the suggestion, unfortunately OpenLDAP needs something inside that directory. I have to initially run OpenLDAP with a config file, then convert the file into the directory + contents and run OpenLDAP with that.

Comment: As it turns out, I can run OpenLDAP without -f or -F and it looks first for the directory then the config file automatically. But my question still stands in case I need to do something similar in the future - how do I pass different parameters based on other tests/decisions?